# Ruby undefined method `to_sentence'

Tags: ruby

I'm doing a Ruby training on Codewars and I'm stuck on something.

I have to do this :

```
list([ {name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'}, {name: 'Maggie'} ])
# returns 'Bart, Lisa & Maggie'
```

So I tried this code:

```
def list names
  names.map(&:values).flatten.to_sentence(last_word_connector: ' &')
end
```

But unfortunately, I have this error :

```
main.rb:4:in `list': undefined method `to_sentence' for ["Bart", "Lisa", "Maggie", "Homer", "Marge"]:Array (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  to_set
    from main.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

I've been searching for hours and I don't understand why 'to_sentence' doesn't work...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Array#to_sentence`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activesupport/Array#to_sentence-instance_method) is an ActiveSupport method. ActiveSupport is a Ruby gem that adds a lot of useful utility methods to existing classes. You'll need to install and require the gem to make sure it's loaded

```
gem install activesupport
```

Then, at the top of your file,

```
require 'active_support/all'
```

If you're writing a Rails project, then you get ActiveSupport for free. But if you're writing standard Ruby, you have to require it.

Comment: Thanks! It words way better. Is there a way to do the same with something more 'vanilla'?

Comment: @ÉdouardBernard : You can define your own `to_sentence` method. Active Support isn't doing anything else.

Comment: If you are joining all but the last element of the array with `', '` can you get all but the last element of an array as a subarray?